# Are images in HTML emails blocked by default on Samsung S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, email

I have a client complaining that images in his email signature are not showing on his Samsung S3. So I wanted to know if they are either blocked by default or the email client is set to display plaintext emails by default?

Comment: It may be setup to not *load* images by default. Many mail clients are setup like that, for good reasons :)

Comment: Thanks Izzy. I don't suppose you happen to know if the native email app on Samsung S3 does this?

Comment: Is he using the email app or the gmail one? I think almost every email app will hide images by default, and usually at the top there will be a button that will enable showing of the images (with gmail, you press a Show Pictures button), and most likely, after pressing that, the client will give you an option to "Always show pictures from this sender" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks bassmadrigal. I believe he's using the email app so yes it would make sense if images don't show by default. So there's nothing I can do about it!